# Do I need an International Driving Permit to drive in Muscat?

Tags: driving-licenses, german-residents, oman, muscat

In Muscat, can we drive with a German driving license, which is in German, or should we translate it to an International Driving Permit, to drive in Muscat?

Comment: No, you need an International Driving Permit. http://internationaldrivingpermit.org/country/oman/

Comment: Thanks i already converted my license.The front page is still written in German language and tout of the pages inside the book there is an English page and the categories are stamped on the French page.

Comment: @HankyPanky +1 add that as an answer and I'll upvote

Comment: Thanks@Dorothy and @MarkMayo. I have added an answer, didn't think a simple comment was worth being an answer so I have put some research into it.

Comment: If you have a German EU driving license (credit card size) you can definitely drive a rental in Oman without IDP. If you have the pink or even the gray paper, you should consider to get an EU driving license.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I made a comment earlier which implied that you will not be able to drive on your national license as a visitor in Oman. My comment was based on this statement on the [IDP website](http://internationaldrivingpermit.org/country/oman/)

> All visitors who plan to drive in Oman must make sure they obtain an IDP in their home country or country of residence before they travel.

However, after some research it appears like the answer is  **No you don't need an IDP**; You can drive using your National License if you are a visitor. If you receive a residence permit then you will have to apply for a local driving license in Oman.

[ExpatArrivals](http://www.expatarrivals.com/oman/transport-and-driving-in-oman) states that

> **Expats can drive in Oman with their national driver's licence if on a visitor visa**. Anyone applying for a residence visa for Oman may also drive with their national driver's licence. However, once the residence visa is issued expats need an Omani driver's licence.

(The emphasis is mine)

[JustLanded](https://www.justlanded.com/english/Oman/Oman-Guide/Travel-Leisure/Driving-rules-and-regulations) states that:

> While on a visitors visa, expats are allowed to drive with their own national driver’s licence. Once a residence visa is issued, expats have to obtain an Omani driver’s licence

[WikiProcedure](https://www.wikiprocedure.com/index.php/Oman_-_Obtain_a_Driving_License#Eligibility) states

> NOTE: A foreign tourist can use his own country's driving licence or an international driving license for 3 months.

[AutoDriverClub](http://www.adcidl.com/Driving-in-Oman.html) states that

> A short-term visitor in possession of a valid driver license and presence of International driving permit may drive in Oman, but any Oman resident must have an Omani driver license.

Lastly, one extremely reliable source, [GOV.UK](https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/oman/safety-and-security), informs British public that

> If you are a visitor you can drive a rental car using your UK driving licence (both parts must be shown). If you are applying for residence in Oman you can also drive on a UK driving licence until your residency permit is issued. After that, you will need to apply for an Omani driving licence within 6 weeks of receiving your residence card. Residents may find that a UK driving licence is not deemed valid for insurance purposes if an accident occurs.

Although you have clearly mentioned Germany as your nationality but since I can't find an official German reference I don't see any reason why Germany would be an exception to this practice.

Hence it can be safely said that **as a tourist Yes You Can drive in Oman legally using your German License**. Nowhere do I see any requirement of Translation either.

Comment: That sounds 100% right to me.